# Unity 2018.1.3f1 Player's Rigidbody2D and Box Collider 2D are not colliding with collidable tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot seem to find a way to collide the player with objects that are supposed to stop the player. For example, when I move the player up to a wall of trees, it just moves through them (and bounces away from the grid alignment slightly) like the player were a ghost.

[image]

[image]

And below is the code I'm using as far as Player's movement is concerned:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : Character {

    Direction currentDir;
    Vector2 input;
    bool IsMoving = false;
    Vector3 startpos;
    Vector3 endpos;
    float t;

    public Sprite upsprite;
    public Sprite rightsprite;
    public Sprite downsprite;
    public Sprite leftsprite;

    public float walkSpeed = 3f;

    public bool isAllowedToMove = true;

    private Rigidbody2D myRB;

    void Start()
    {
        isAllowedToMove = true;
        myRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    protected override void Update () {
        if (! IsMoving && isAllowedToMove) {
            input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) > Mathf.Abs(input.y))
                input.y = 0;
            else
                input.x = 0;

            if (input != Vector2.zero) {
                if (input.x < 0) {
                    currentDir = Direction.Left;
                }
                if (input.x > 0) {
                    currentDir = Direction.Right;
                }
                if (input.y < 0) {
                    currentDir = Direction.Down;
                }
                if (input.y > 0) {
                    currentDir = Direction.Up;
                }

                switch (currentDir) {
                    case Direction.Up:
                        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = upsprite;
                        break;
                    case Direction.Right:
                        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = rightsprite;
                        break;
                    case Direction.Down:
                        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = downsprite;
                        break;
                    case Direction.Left:
                        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = leftsprite;
                        break;
                }

                StartCoroutine (Move (transform));
            }

            myRB.velocity = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * walkSpeed, myRB.velocity.y);
            myRB.velocity = new Vector2 (myRB.velocity.x, Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") * walkSpeed);

            if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > -0.5f) 
            {
                myRB.velocity = new Vector2 (0f, myRB.velocity.y);
            }

            if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") > -0.5f) 
            {
                myRB.velocity = new Vector2(myRB.velocity.y, 0f);
            }
        }

        base.Update ();
    }

    public IEnumerator Move(Transform entity)
    {
        IsMoving = true;
        startpos = entity.position;
        t = 0;

        endpos = new Vector3(startpos.x + System.Math.Sign(input.x), startpos.y + System.Math.Sign(input.y), startpos.z);

            while(t < 1f)
            {
                t += Time.deltaTime * walkSpeed;
                entity.position = Vector3.Lerp(startpos, endpos, t);
                yield return null;
            }

        IsMoving = false;
        yield return 0;
    }
}

enum Direction
{
    Up,
    Right,
    Down,
    Left
}
```

Other things to note are that I made sure to use Rigidbody2D and Box Collider2D components, and I made sure to make the Gravity scale 0 for the player and froze the rotation from the Z axis. Also, I did use Tiled and Tiled2Unity extensions to create the tiles you see in game, despite the preinstalled tilemap assets being a decent choice to create 2d game worlds.

Forgive me if it seems too long, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is with the collision detection. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is the collision code?

Comment: You've made sure both objects have a RigidBody and Colliders?

Comment: @Cory Only the player needs a rigidbody. The other objects do not.

Comment: the tiles have polygon colliders but not box colliders or rigid bodies. Only the player has a boxcollider2d and a rigidbody2d

Comment: @Draco18s good call. Both need a 2d collider, only the player needs a RigidBody. Thanks

Comment: *A* collider is sufficient, @GreenTree. As long as both have one (it doesn't matter what kind).

Comment: Did you make sure to attach a TilemapCollider2D to the tilemap?

Comment: I don't think you've read the description carefully. I said I used Tiled and the Tiled2Unity extension to import what I included as far as the tile to Unity. Even if I did so, it wouldn't allow my character to move...

Comment: have you checked to make sure the player and object layers have collision with each other enabled? i.e make sure the trees arnt getting put in the terrain layer allowing you to walk on them? Edit - Project Settings - 2D, and check to collision matrix

Comment: They are all checked on the collision matrix.